# symfony2 customise error page and extend

Tags: symfony, error-handling, twig

I'm currently stuck with something that sounds really easy : "customize error pages".

I followed the s2 sample to customize these pases ie :

1. Create a new folder app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception
2. c/c the error.html.twig and exception.html.twig from the TwigBundle folder to the new one

At this point it works. I remove everything from the templates and write a simply "hello world", and once I try to reach a non existing page I have my template.

My problem is when I try to use the template developed for my website.

My base template is locate here :

```
webApp/app/Resources/views/Frontend/base.html.twig
```

when I try to use this template I have a Route Not found exception. Here the extends that I tried to use :

```
{%  extends ":Frontend:base.html.twig" %}
{%  extends "::Frontend:base.html.twig" %}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix that ? Or if it's possible to extend the error templates ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would put `base.html.twig` in `webApp/app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` and then extend it with

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
```

Probably I'm missing something, but why would you have Frontend folder in `webApp/app/Resources/views/`? Like if there were a controller named Frontend?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it should be:

```
{% extends "Frontend::base.html.twig" %}
```

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for this very quick reply !
I tried your extend but I still have the same issue : 
> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException
I also think that it's only an issue with the path of the file from the extend but I have no idea how fix it.

Many many thanks